# try catch bad form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

i think i sort of know the answer to this, but there are always many ways to do things (some of which are clearly wrong :) )...

I have a little recursive function to find an employees manager's id. this is being used in a import script and it may be that the persons immediate manager has left (been disabled) so we need to find that employees (the manager) manager (and so on) so we can assign stuff to them. in case it isn't obvious, the EmployeesToDisable is a generic list of employees that are marked as disabled in this import.

I guess what i am really asking, is : is the overhead associated with catching an exception too much of a trade off to make in this instance. and should i be doing this differently.
this does work fine, but feels like it is bad form..

i have code thus:

```
private Guid getMyEnabledManagersID(OnlineEmployee e)
    {
     Employee manager;
     try
     {
      //see if Employee e's manager is in the disabled list.
      manager = (from emp in EmployeesToDisable where emp.EmployeeID.Equals(e.ManagerID) select emp).Single();
      //yes they are, so need to call this again 
      return getMyEnabledManagersID(manager);
     }
     catch
     {
      return e.ManagerID;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving aside the recursion, you should perhaps just  use `SingleOrDefault` and test for null. Actually, you *probably* don't need the full employee object - you can probably suffice with just returning the id (throughout), i.e.

```
private Guid getMyEnabledManagersID(Guid managerId)
{
    var disabled = (from emp in EmployeesToDisable 
                    where emp.EmployeeID == managerId
                    select (Guid?)emp.ManagerID).SingleOrDefault();
    return disabled == null ? managerId : getMyEnabledManagersID(disabled.Value);
}
```

Actually, the *biggest* concern I have with the original form is that it isn't specific to the *type* of exception; it could be "thread abort", "zombie connection", "deadlock", etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. just wondering what the difference (if any in this instance) between using == or .Equals(..

Comment: @nat - readability, mainly. IMO the `==` is more intuitive. In the *general* case you also need to think about "is the first argument null" when using `.Equals`, but this doesn't apply to `Guid` since it is a `struct`

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out *never do that*. That is a "worst practice". The exception is there to tell you that *you have a logic bug in your program*. By catching the exception and continuing on, you hide the logic bug.

Only use Single when you *know*, positively and for sure, that there is exactly one element in the sequence. If there might be other numbers of elements in the list then use First, FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault, or write your own sequence operator; it's not hard to do.

The main reasons to not use this worst practice are:

1) As I said, it hides a bug; those exceptions should *never* be caught because they should *never* be thrown in a working program. The exceptions are there to help you debug your program, not to control its flow.

2) Using exceptions as control flow like this makes it difficult to debug a program. Debuggers are often configured to stop on any exception, whether it is handled or not.  Lots of "expected" exceptions make that harder. Exceptions should never be expected, they should be *exceptional*; that's why they're called "exceptions".

3) The catch catches everything, including stuff that probably indicates a fatal error that should be reported to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other answers,

Try/Catch are very costly operations, your simple if statement is faster in terms of performance then expecting a catch and then following the logic.

Try/Catch should not be part of business logic, instead they should only be part of error handling.

Comment: "very costly" is relative... compared to the cost of *building a LINQ query, checking the local identity manager, composing the query into TSQL, executing the TSQL over a connection, the DB server checking the query-cache, parsing the TSQL, and executing the query, handling the TDS response and performing the projection from TDS*, I think we can say "the exception handling (or lack of) costs exactly zero". Your point about business logic is valid, though.

Comment: Well in this example, he is going to execute TSQL anyway,I am not comparing Try/Catch with TSQL, I am comparing it with "IF" condition that can be simplified to check for results easily

Answer (score 0):

You could use FirstOrDefault() instead of Single and handle the returned null value.