# I want to check which button was clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file-io

Right now I have a main form that copies a file to another directory.

I want to handle the case 'a file of the same name already exists' in a catch statement.

I want this to be done by it popping up another window asking whether to replace or keep via buttons. Then using an if statement to check which button was clicked

Current code:

```
        catch (IOException x)
            {
                Copy copy = new Copy();
                copy.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Goal:

```
        catch (IOException x)
            {
                Copy copy = new Copy();
                copy.ShowDialog();

                    if (//Replace button was clicked)
                        do this
                    else if (//Keep button was clicked)
                        do this
            }
```

I can't seem to find the methods that serve this purpose.

Comment: I would rather use the catch for exceptions I cannot handle. So in your case if you already know this issue could rise, than you could or perhaps should check if the file already exists yourself.

Comment: Why do not use a simple MessageBox with YesNo buttons? (And really do not use exceptions to handle this kind of decisions. A simple File.Exists should resolve the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your Copy dialog return the `DialogResult` when the button is clicked. For instance you could use `DialogRsult.OK` for the Replace button and the `DialogResult.Cancel` for the Keep button. Something like this:

When clicked Replace button within the Copy dialog you can set this within the `Replace_Click` event handler

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

set in the similar way the `DialogResult.Cancel` in the `Keep_Click` event handler

and you could call your dialog like this:

```
Copy copy = new Copy();
DialogResult dr = copy.ShowDialog();  

if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
    //Replace clicked
else if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    //Keep clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [DialogResult](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816145) class instead.

You want something like this:

```
catch (IOException x)
{
   DialogResult dr = new DialogResult ();
   dr.ShowDialog(); 

   if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
      MessageBox.Show ("File replaced.");

   else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
      MessageBox.Show ("File kept.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use exceptions to handle this kind of situations.
Just test if file exists and use a simple MessageBox with YesNo buttons

```
sourceFile = "Your_Source_File_To_Copy";
string destFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
if(File.Exists(destFile))
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("File already exist! Do you wish to overwrite?", 
                                      "Warning!",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
         // Overwrite
    else
         // Do something else
}
```

As [Mr Lippert says in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802658/try-catch-bad-form?rq=1),

> Exceptions are there to
>   help you debug your program, not to control its flow.

Comment: Actually, this is precisely the situation in which you cannot avoid using exceptions to control flow, unfortunately. Suppose you check to see if the file is there. OK, it's there. Then *between the check and the attempt to open it*, the file is deleted by another process. You get an exception. Suppose it is there, but *you can't write it because it is locked by another process*. You get an exception. "Exogenous" exceptions like that indicate that some fact about the external world is not as expected, and you have to deal with it.

Comment: In the example you linked to, the exception was not exogenous; you can know ahead of time whether the exception will be thrown, and therefore you can avoid it, and therefore you don't have to handle it. Those pleasant characteristics are not true of the file system.

Comment: @EricLippert of course your analysis is very correct and now I am noticing something that I should have noticed immediately, however my opinion on the pattern used by OP is still negative. I am feeling that inside the Exception he/she tries to repeat the same action that has lead to the exception. What guarantees do we have that the problem does not repeat indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Form.ShowDialog method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Code Excerpt from MSDN:

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK. 
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox. 
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the file existence before copying:

```
    if (File.Exists(destFileName))
    {
        Copy copy = new Copy();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult res = copy.ShowDialog();
        if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, true);
    }
    else
    {
        File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    }
```

Also set the `DialogResult` property in the `Copy` form appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps implementing your own result is what you are looking for.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = new Form2().ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    ButtonResult buttonResult;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public new ButtonResult ShowDialog()
    {
        base.ShowDialog();
        return buttonResult;
    }

    private void KeepButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonResult = ButtonResult.Keep;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ReplaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonResult = ButtonResult.Replace;
        this.Close();
    }
}

public enum ButtonResult
{
    None = 0,
    Keep = 1,
    Replace = 2,
}
```